# Display and writing of image in java

Tags: java, image

I am unable to display the image as there's problem in the main method and i am not sure whether did i write the image correctly. Sorry, I am really new to Java.

```
public class Display extends JPanel
{
String path = "C:/Users/asus/workspace/Code/src/7horses.jpg";
File file = new File(path); 

static BufferedImage img;
img = ImageIO.read(new File(file));

public static BufferedImage CopyImage (File file)
{
    BufferedImage cImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = cImg.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();  
    File saveImage = new File("C:/Users/asus/workspace/Code/src", saveAs);
    ImageIO.write(cImg, "png", saveImage); 
    return cImg;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Show Image");
    LoadImage panel = new BufferedImage CopyImage(file);//
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(panel);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

After duplicate the image, i am not sure how to display the duplicate copy. Below was the code which i initially use for loading and displaying.

```
public class LoadImage extends JPanel
{
BufferedImage img;
String path = "C:/Users/asus/workspace/MP/src/7horses.jpg";
File file = new File(path);

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

public LoadImage()
{
    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(file); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Show Image");
    LoadImage panel = new LoadImage();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(panel);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with this code..

- `path` and `file` cannot be accessed by `main()` because they are not `static` and main is. Meaning when `main()` is ran, neither of `path` or `file` exist.
- `LoadImage panel = new BufferedImage CopyImage(file)` is not valid Java - I'm not sure what you were trying to do but I guess you want to remove the `new BufferedImage` part
- `img = ImageIO.read(new File(file));` - you can't run this statement outside a method or static block as it requires handling of an `IOException`
- `ImageIO.read(new File(file));` - `file` is already of type `File` and you are passing it to a type `File`, not necessary.  `ImageIO.read(file);` would do
- `saveAs` hasn't been defined anywhere.
- `ImageIO.write(cImg, "png", saveImage);` can throw an `IOException` so you need to add a `try-catch` around it like in the `LoadImage()` constructor or append `throws IOException` to your method signature like so `public static BufferedImage CopyImage (File file) throws IOException`
- You are referencing `LoadImage` which looks like it's trying to do exactly what `Display` does in a slightly different way. I'm not sure what to advise here because I don't understand the intention but I think perhaps replace `LoadImage` in the `Display` code with `Display`

Comment: +0 ; you can't `img = ImageIO.read(new File(file))`? well, actually, you *can*; `static BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(file));` would work exactly as it should

Comment: and how do you deal with the thrown `IOException` in that case?

Comment: either provide a wrapper method suppressing/handling the exception or use a `static {}` block for this - anyway, I wasn't pointing out that you *can have checked exceptions in initializers* (because out, obviously, can't) - I pointed out that you *can run statements outside a method block like that*. Rephrasing that statement to, e.g. "you can't have a method call throwing a checked exception outside of method block" would be OK

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

1. Use `ImageIO` to retrieve a `BufferedImage` from your file.
2. Using an `ImagePanel` that can use a Buffered Image to display on
   your `JFrame`

It would be something more like that:

```
public class Display extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String path = "C:/Users/asus/workspace/Code/src/7horses.jpg";
    private static final File file = new File(path);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Show Image");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(image);//
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BufferedImage image;

        public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I reckon this is exactly what OP had in his mind - at least I understood him so. If you'd also point out the errors in the OPs code as Ross Drew did, you'd deserve a accept on this.

Answer (score 0):

What is a LoadImage? Unless it's both a BufferedImage AND a Container your code won't even compile.
And as a class can't be both a Container and a BufferedImage at the same time (given that both are classes, not interfaces, and multiple inheritance at class level doesn't exist in Java) your code can't work.

You're going to have to figure out how to correctly initialise your LoadImage instance, and only the documentation (and possibly source) of that class is going to help you.